# Spring boot application failed to start with 2.1.8

Tags: spring-boot

I have created a sample spring boot app with web and actuator dependency. App is starting fine and working fine in my IDE (STS). But when i run the jar using commnd line getting below exception.

When I down graded my spring boot version to 2.1.7 This error is not occuring.App is starting fine in both IDE and command line.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.web.tomcat.TomcatMetricsAutoConfiguration
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:413) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:253) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:130) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at com.learntech.teamtracker.SignupApplication.main(SignupApplication.java:10) [classes!/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [signup-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [signup-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) [signup-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [signup-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:569) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:416) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:137) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:402) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/micrometer/core/instrument/MeterRegistry
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.addAllMethods(ReflectUtils.java:443) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.getMethods(Enhancer.java:632) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:667) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanFactoryAwareGeneratorStrategy.generate(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:252) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:582) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93) ~[signup-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipInflaterInputStream.java:52) ~[signup-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        ... 51 common frames omitted
```

my pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Did you rebuild it? `mvn clean package`?

Comment: I have tested the app with `2.1.8.RELEASE` and it is working fine. Packages must have been broken. Please clean & update the project and try it again.